# Serial up and down voting by a moderator

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, status-declined, moderators

How many times can a moderator or super user vote a user over time? I know if I go to another user's profile and up and down voted multiple Q&A then the votes could get retracted as serial votes. So is there a time between votes that would not red flag? I believe I may be serial down voted slowly. Can there be a cap to how many times one person can down vote another? I feel I ask relevant questions but they are not a smart as they are.

Comment: What feature is being requested here?

Comment: about 3 upvotes per day won't trigger the automatic reversal and, if blended with votes on other posts, it won't alert mods. I know because I've been serially upvoted a couple times and they got smart about it so that I actually had to point it out after a while. Downvotes are more noticeable. I'd say no more than 1 or 2 a day to avoid suspicion.

Comment: @DavidZ a max number of times 1 person can down vote another same person.

Comment: Generally, I would seriously advise you to consider that some of your posts may simply need improvement, and to take those downvotes as suggestions (from a single person or several, but from looking at the pattern I wouldn't draw a serial-voting conclusion) to improve those posts.

Comment: @Jen I think it's pretty safe to say that's not going to be implemented.

Comment: @DavidZ and rest.  Thank you all for checking. any thing about a cap on down votes from one to another?

Answer (score 9):

Voting by moderators works exactly the same way it works for other users, and moderators are subject to the same voting restrictions as other users.

The serial voting detection and reversal mechanism is an automatic system process (no human intervention) and it works the same on moderators as it does on unprivileged users.

Finally, the system provides some information to moderators on long-term voting tends and cliques which allows for possible human intervention in cases where some user attempts to slip in a slow trickle of votes directed at another user.

Answer (score 3):

Also mods can't vote more than once to a post. The only possibility to vote multiple times, if you use multiple accounts for the task. Doing this "correctly", the SE has no way to know, that they are socks. But they are watching quite sophistically the cases, where they aren't done correctly.

If you want to check, if you are serially downvoted, you can do this by sorting the reputation changes in your profile page by time. By default, it is sorted by post. Click [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/102013/jen?tab=reputation&sort=time).

The downvotes in short time, but to your different posts, are coming probably from the same person.

What is visible on your reputation changes, that you aren't serial downvoted, but somebody doesn't like your posts.

It doesn't need mod privileges to serial downvote somebody.

You are enthusiast in the Physics, and a high school beginner. You have a lot of ideas, and a lot of questions. Some of them are good, some not.

In your place my main problem wouldn't be the downs, but the closes of my questions.